# convert date into different format

Tags: java, date, date-format, date-formatting

I am trying to convert date into user required format. I want date in all format.
But formatted date is wrong please help.

```
package DateFormat;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormat
{
    DateFormat() throws ParseException
    {
    String dateFormats[] =
    {
            "YYYY/MM/DD",
            "DD/MM/YYYY",
            "DD-MM-YYYY",
    };


    for (int i = 0; i < dateFormats.length; i++)
    {

        String newDate = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormats[i]).format(new Date());
        System.out.println(newDate);
    }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
    new DateFormat();
    }
}
```

output is

```
2016/04/98
98/04/2016
98-04-2016
```

Thank you.

Comment: Because, using wrong format. Please see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for supported formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going wrong because of java code syntax case sensitive.
Pls check the right date and time pattern at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Your String array of patterns should be transformed to:

```
String dateFormats[] =
{
        "yyyy/MM/dd",
        "dd/MM/yyyy",
        "dd-MM-yyyy",
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
D   Day in year Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
```

from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

So, formats should look like:

```
String dateFormats[] =
{
        "yyyy/MM/dd",
        "dd/MM/yyyy",
        "dd-MM-yyyy",
};
```

Comment: The `YYYY` should be lowercase too, `yyyy`.